# jq command to check if a json array response has particular user name and state as approved using shell script

Tags: jquery, bash, sh, jq

I have a json array response below,

```
[
    {
        "user": {
            "login": "TOM",
        },
        "body": "",
        "state": "APPROVED",
    },
    {
        "user": {
            "login": "JERRY",
        },
        "body": "",
        "state": "APPROVED",
    },
    {
        "user": {
            "login": "ANDY",
        },
        "body": "",
        "state": "REJECTED",
    }
]
```

I am working on code to check if only when user **Jerry** exists and has state **APPROVED** I should set a variable value as true else it should be false.

In above case I should get true and in either of the below cases it should be false

```
[
    {
        "user": {
            "login": "TOM",
        },
        "body": "",
        "state": "APPROVED",
    },
    {
        "user": {
            "login": "JERRY",
        },
        "body": "",
        "state": "REJECTED",
    },
    {
        "user": {
            "login": "ANDY",
        },
        "body": "",
        "state": "REJECTED",
    }
]
```

or

```
[
    {
        "user": {
            "login": "TOM",
        },
        "body": "",
        "state": "APPROVED",
    },
    {
        "user": {
            "login": "ANDY",
        },
        "body": "",
        "state": "REJECTED",
    }
]
```

I tried below code but I am not able to address both the condition

```
hasJerry = false
if [ (jq -r '.[].user.login | index("JTHOM949")') && (jq -r '.[].state' == "APPROVED") ]; then

    hasJerry = true

fi
```

can someone help me to fix this script.

Comment: Your JSON is malformed. The last key-value pair in an object must not have a trailing comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have jq output `true` or `false`, thus set the variable directly. Within jq, you can use `any` to find "at least one item" that matches your criteria.

```bash
hasJerry="$(jq 'any(.user.login == "JERRY" and .state == "APPROVED")' input.json)"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/TghJUmO6f7O)

Note that your Bash script has errors (e.g. whitespace around `=` with the variable assignment), as does your (sample) JSON input (e.g. commas after the last field in an object). Please correct them first.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning the raw True or False strings, you could test the return status:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

user=$1

while [ -z "$user" ]; do
  printf 'Enter user: ' 
  read -r user
  printf \\n
done

if jq -e --arg user "$user" \
  '
.users | 
any(
  .user.login == ($user | ascii_upcase) and
  .state == "APPROVED"
)
' input.json > /dev/null
then
  printf '%s is approved!\n' "$user"
else
  printf 'Non-aproved user %s!\n' "$user"
fi
```